# AttributeError: module 'pyexiv2' has no attribute 'ImageMetadata' | Python 3.7

Tags: python, image, metadata, exif, pyexiv2

I've been trying to run the following code:

```
exif = pyexiv2.ImageMetadata(image_file)
exif.read()
```

on Python 3.7.0 and it yields an error `AttributeError: module 'pyexiv2' has no attribute 'ImageMetadata'`

I haven't used pyexiv2 before but the example illustrated [here](https://python3-exiv2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) is similar to mine and I presume it works fine. I'm also not sure if pyexiv2 is fully supported for Python 3.
Please Advise.

You can find the script I'm working with [here](https://github.com/UASLab/ImageAnalysis/blob/master/scripts/99-new-camera.py)

Comment: your example link shows `pyexiv2.metadata.ImageMetadata`, not `pyexiv2.ImageMetadata`

Comment: @furas You can find the reference under the title `buffer` with the code `meta = pyexiv2.ImageMetadata("lena.jpg")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This module uses

```
import pyexiv2
```

but you have to install `py3exiv2` instead of `pyexiv2` - you can see it in first line of [Tutorial](https://python3-exiv2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html)

---

But it uses some `C/C++` code and it needs other modules in `C/C++`.

On Linux I had to install

```
apt install exiv2

apt install python3-dev

apt install libexiv2-dev

apt install libboost-python-dev
```

and later

```
pip install py3exiv2
```

(not `pyexiv2`)

See `Dependences` on page [Developers](https://python3-exiv2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/developers.html)

On Linux I  have installed compiler `C/C++` - `gcc` - but you may have to install it on other systems.

Comment: Still fails to work after installing the following dependencies `exiv2` `boost-python3` and `py3exiv2`

Comment: did you uninstall `pyexiv2` ? Maybe you have two Python installed and you install `py3exiv2` in other Python - you may use `python -m pip install ...` to install for Python which you use to run `python script.py`

Comment: I would first unistall `pyexiv2` and check if still can `import pyexiv2` to confirm that it was really uninstalled. And later I would use `python -m pip install py3exiv2` to install it - and it should compile it - so you should see if it has problem to find needed elements. It needs modules with `*-dev` which have source code in `C/C++`

Comment: I believe your method has worked to some extent but now the `import pyexiv2` yields an error. I've reported that issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65936143/symbol-not-found-referenced-from-expected-in-flat-namespace-macos-big-sur)