# Modify or Delete Exif tag 'Orientation' in Python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, exif

I need some of my pictures to be displayed with the same orientation whether the software reads the exif data or not. One solution (the only one that could fit actually) would be to rotate the image according to the exif tag if it exists and then delete or modify this tag to '1'.

**Example**
*Let's say an image has the Orientation exif tag set to 3. What I want to do is rotate this image according to this tag and save it this way. So that a software that doesn't interpret exif will still display it in the good orientation. Though if the exif tag Orientation is still set to 3, then a software that interprets Exif will rotate my already-rotated image. So that's why I want to set this tag to 1 (which means : no orientation) or delete it.*

**My final goal is that the image will always be displayed the same, whichever software I use to open it.**

There are a lot of questions about that, Exif and Python, blah blah blah. Here is a list of libs that I heard about :

- Pyexiv2 : Not suitable, I'm currently using Python 3.3 with Pillow
- Gexiv2 : Looks like a bit platform specific
- EXIF.py
- [Pexif](https://github.com/bennoleslie/pexif) : Looks like the most recent one ?

What are the best practices ? Is there a pure python solution ? (Which I could install with pip and put it in my requirements.txt) Is there some kind of new lib I could use which is specific to Python3 ?

My only problem right now is to modify and write those exif data to the image file. I have no problem to read exif data, and rotate the image according to the orientation tag. Any tips or advice on that ?

Comment: Just curious to know why would you want to do this "and then delete or modify this tag to '1'." ?

Comment: If the tag is set to '1', then it means "No specific orientation". So the softwares that interpret exif won't rotate the image. If this tag doesn't exist, it's totally the same. I'll edit my post to make it more clear.

Comment: Another possibility is to use [exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) as described [here](http://pythonpath.wordpress.com/2013/04/01/working-with-pil-and-exif). You firstly extract exif data with exiftool into dictionary, process and save the image as you want (like rotate) and then copy modified exif data into new file with exiftool again.

Comment: @Ondro: does exiftool support modifying tags, or does it need PIL to do it? 'cause PIL has no support for Python 3.x.

Comment: @Peihui PIL doesn't support Python 3.x, but Pillow (the friendly fork of PIL) does.

Comment: @Peihul as it is described on linked webpage, you read exif data into python dictionary, then you can modified it as you want and using exiftool you will write it back to image file.

Comment: Anyway as I said in the OP, I would really prefer a pure-python solution (if it exists)

Comment: @Depado: OK. I think the use of exiftool is promising to answer your need and very worth trying. :)

Comment: In that case I would use Gexiv2... It's platform specific too, but at least I don't make calls to subprocess...

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606587

Comment: It is related because I heard about pyexiv2 on that question. Which doesn't apply in my case because I'm using Python 3.3 and Pillow.

Comment: Quick note: `piexif` is definitely the best-behaved solution for Python 3.

Answer (score 16):

#### note:

This answer works for Python2.7 - you can probably just swap Pillow for PIL in Python3, but I can't speak to that from experience. Note that unlike pyexiv2 and most of the other packages that allow you to modify EXIF metadata, the pexif library is standalone and pure python, so it does not need to bind to any C libraries that may not be present on your machine.

#### overview:

You need to use two separate tools for the two steps:

- [pexif](https://github.com/bennoleslie/pexif) to modify the metadata (EXIF tag)
- [PIL](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PIL) to rotate the image

#### pexif part:

Four steps:

- open the image
- check orientation (needed later for rotation)
- change orientation to 1
- save the image

If the orientation tag isn't found, an AttributeError results, hence the `try:`. Also note that pexif needs the orientation tag to be a list (with one element).

```py
import pexif
img = pexif.JpegFile.fromFile(temp_dir + filename)

try:
  #Get the orientation if it exists
  orientation = img.exif.primary.Orientation[0]
  img.exif.primary.Orientation = [1]
  img.writeFile(temp_dir + filename)
```

#### PIL part:

Now to rotate the image. A source for the meaning of the possible orientations (used to generate the lookup table for rotations) is [here](http://www.daveperrett.com/articles/2012/07/28/exif-orientation-handling-is-a-ghetto/).

- open the image
- apply the necessary rotation/reflection
- save the image

```py
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open(temp_dir + filename)
if orientation is 6: img = img.rotate(-90)
elif orientation is 8: img = img.rotate(90)
elif orientation is 3: img = img.rotate(180)
elif orientation is 2: img = img.transpose(Image.FLIP_LEFT_RIGHT)
elif orientation is 5: img = img.rotate(-90).transpose(Image.FLIP_LEFT_RIGHT)
elif orientation is 7: img = img.rotate(90).transpose(Image.FLIP_LEFT_RIGHT)
elif orientation is 4: img = img.rotate(180).transpose(Image.FLIP_LEFT_RIGHT)

#save the result
img.save(temp_dir + filename)
```

#### put it all together:

```py
if ctype == 'image/jpeg':
  from PIL import Image
  import pexif

  img = pexif.JpegFile.fromFile(temp_dir + filename)

  try:
    #Get the orientation if it exists
    orientation = img.exif.primary.Orientation[0]
    img.exif.primary.Orientation = [1]
    img.writeFile(temp_dir + filename)

    #now rotate the image using the Python Image Library (PIL)
    img = Image.open(temp_dir + filename)
    if orientation is 6: img = img.rotate(-90)
    elif orientation is 8: img = img.rotate(90)
    elif orientation is 3: img = img.rotate(180)
    elif orientation is 2: img = img.transpose(Image.FLIP_LEFT_RIGHT)
    elif orientation is 5: img = img.rotate(-90).transpose(Image.FLIP_LEFT_RIGHT)
    elif orientation is 7: img = img.rotate(90).transpose(Image.FLIP_LEFT_RIGHT)
    elif orientation is 4: img = img.rotate(180).transpose(Image.FLIP_LEFT_RIGHT)

    #save the result
    img.save(temp_dir + filename)
  except: pass
```

Comment: This is a great piece of info that not even the big services get right... http://www.daveperrett.com/articles/2012/07/28/exif-orientation-handling-is-a-ghetto/ Thanks for sharing this!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at EXIF and Pyxif in this Git repository:
https://github.com/hMatoba

Both offer simple and pure Python methods for reading and modifying EXIF tags. In combination with PIL or Pillow, these libs are fantastic and they don't come with the overhead of other huge packages, such as pyexif2.

Answer (score -2):

You can use Pillow save Exif data

```
img.save(output, img_format, quality, exif=img_info.get('exif'))
```

Comment: I do know that. Though you can try to modify those data with Pillow, you won't be able to do it. I want to modify the exif data before saving it.