# Manually set Exif property and maintain image's original width and height in Python

Tags: python, image, exif, python-imaging-library

When I do `Image.open` in python it sometimes flips the width and height of the image. After some research (see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26561800/pil-image-size-returns-the-opposite-width-height)'s explaination), it seems that if the image has `Exif Orientation metadata` associated with it, then that will cause applications that respect that property to rotate it.

So first I test my image's Exif property by doing

```
identify -verbose image.JPG | grep Orientation
```

It returns **6**, which means the image has the property and therefore will be flipped. If the response is **1** then the image does not have `Exif Orientation metadata` and therefore is not flipped. Since I do not want to flip the image, I tried setting the `Exif property` manually by taking a suggestion from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22045882/modify-or-delete-exif-tag-orientation-in-python).

So I tried setting `orientation.exif.primary.Orientation[0] = 1` manually in my code. Like this:

```
from PIL import Image
import pexif


orientation = pexif.JpegFile.fromFile('image.JPG')

print("BEFORE:")
print(orientation.exif.primary.Orientation[0])

orientation.exif.primary.Orientation[0] = 1

print("AFTER:")
print(orientation.exif.primary.Orientation[0])


img = Image.open('image.JPG')
print(img.size)
```

This corrects prints **1** after **AFTER** however, it does not actually set it to 1 in real life because when I run `identify -verbose image.JPG | grep Orientation` again, it is still showing **6**. So how do I actually get around this issue and not have the image's width and height flipped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not take credit for this. This [post](https://superuser.com/questions/435443/how-can-i-modify-the-exif-orientation-tag-of-an-image) from Superuser solved my issue.

Fix:

```
import os
os.system("exiftool -Orientation=1 -n image.JPG")
```

This sets the orientation of the actual image to 1. The code I had in the original question changes the orientation of the image object I created, not the actual image itself.